# how to suppress subreport in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, suppress

I'm still new to Crystal Reports, and am completely stumped.  I have a table of 100 accounts (fields are acct_id and sub_ind, which is '1' for all 100 accounts).  I want to suppress the subreport only if the account is on the table.  I've tried multiple possibilities in the suppress formula (x-2).  I've gotten the entire report suppressed for everyone but the accounts on the table; I've gotten the subreport suppressed, except that a box comes up where the subreport would be.  Is there a solution that would suppress the subreport only for the accounts on the table?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing a black box outline, right click on the subreport, go to Format Subreport, click on the Border tab.  Make all of the Line Styles "None".

If you have the subreport in its own section you can right click in the grey part part to the left of the screen, go to Section Expert, and then under the sections find the section where the subreport is located and click on it.  On the common tab about 1/2 way down you'll see a "Suppress Blank Section", click the check box.

Hope this helps.